# Find out when the memory card was removed

Tags: linux, logging

A very strange thing happened today. My roommate was complaining that his memory card went missing this afternoon. And now I found that my memory card is also missing. I don't know what to say.

It can't be someone staling it. If so he/she could have taken the phone itself or the two laptops in my room. Now I want to know when the memory card was ejected.

How do I find that? It should be logged somewhere in the system logs(dmesg), right?

Comment: @Firelord I have root access, but I can't seem to `grep` the output of dmesg. I can't filter out any relevant information.

Comment: Your Android version? I asked it because in my Android 4.2.1 many important logs are under `/data/log_other_mode/` but my Lollipop doesn't have such location. Also, do `cat /proc/kmsg` and `cat /proc/last_kmsg` (once saw it [here](http://bootloader.wikidot.com/linux:android:kmsg)).

Comment: @Firelord I am running 4.4.2. What keywork should I use to filter the logs? "mmc"? `dmesg | grep -i mmc` does not provide anything. It only brings up something related to `mmcqd` ([Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12764920/)). I am currently going trough kmsg, but seem to be getting the same thing.

Comment: Sorry, that I can't help much because my Lollipop device doesn't have any support for external SD card but based on JB I was able to see keywords like `EXTERNAL_STORAGE`  inside `/data/log_other_mode/kernel_log`. My question is, where is the SD card slot in the device? Can the card be pulled out without shutting down the device? If not, then the logs may not show anything good because after a reboot I suppose Android would have rewritten the logs. But keep searching.

Comment: @Firelord I checked the uptime, and it has not been shut down for days. But the dmesg messages seem to be incomplete. It does not start from time 0.